# How do we set up a Docker daemon SSH connection with a bastion server?

Tags: ssh, docker

Docker supports the notion of using SSH to connect to the Docker daemon, but I was wondering is it possible to chain the connection so we connect to a bastion server which then connects to the real docker daemon via SSH?

Comment: I'am not a linux expert but the correct term you look for  is a reverse proxy so check it with ssh, a lot of howto seem published for that matter.

Comment: not really, a bastion server is something we would SSH to ( https://www.davidbegin.com/creating-an-aws-bastion-host-with-terraform/ ) then we use that to SSH to something inside the VPC rather than exposing SSH every node to the outside world

Comment: That's exactly what ProxyJump is for, configure a host in your ssh_config and you're golden.

Comment: And how do you utilize that with Docker SSH daemon connection?  We're only allowed to put in the ssh:// URI